# MATLAB - create matrix with submatrices

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say I have three different 2x2 submatrices, and I want to create a big 6x6 matrix in Matlab in which the three submatrices appear on the diagonal, and all the other values are 0.  How can I do this wihtout entering all the zeros explicitly?  I just started learning MatLab and I really am quite a novice.  If someone could help me with this I would be very grateful!  Later I have to do this with more matrices, and entering all the zeros is becoming a pain!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Suppose your matrices are named `M1`, `M2`, `M3`, write `blkdiag(M1, M2, M2)`. If any of your matrices is sparse, so will be the result. Otherwise it will be dense.

Comment: Great!  Thanks a lot!  I wasn't aware of the blkdiag-command :)

Answer (score 0):

Also one could define `a=zeros(6);` then you can start type `a(1:2,1:2)=a11, a(3:4,3:4)=a22,a(5:6,5:6)=a33`, where a11, a22 and a33 are your 2×2 matrices. A little bit long, but it works. Like another option.

Answer (score -1):

you can use

> A=zeros(6,6)

to create a 6*6 matrix with all array zero.

Comment: This is incomplete answer that has no solution for diagonal blocks